# How to turn multiple join conditions into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a beginner in SQL, and can't figure out how to obtain the query results I am looking for. I have a table called Payment and a table called User. Payment has fields amount, recipient_id, sender_id. User has id (which corresponds to sender_id or recipient_id) and email. I want the amount, message, sender_email, recipient_email of all the payments. What SQL query would allow me to do this? I tried the following query. but it produce two rows for one Payment row when recipient_id and sender_id has different user id.

I want to get two different user information(recipient_id and sender_id) in one row.

```sql
Select Payment.amount, Payment.message, User.id
FROM Payment
INNER JOIN User
ON (Payment.recipient_id = User.id
or Payment.sender_id = User.id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want two separate JOINs: one for sender and one for recipient like so:

```
SELECT
  Payment.amount, Payment.message, PaymentUser.email AS PaymentUserEmail, SenderUser.email AS SenderUserEmail
FROM Payment
  INNER JOIN User PaymentUser ON Payment.recipient_id = PaymentUser.id
  INNER JOIN User SenderUser ON Payment.sender_id = SenderUser.id;
```

That will include separate columns for each of recipient and sender, and you can provide aliases for the columns (`AS PaymentUserEmail`) and tables (`User PaymentUser`).